# flot time graph using UTC datetime without timezone offset- How can I make it use local datetime

Tags: flot

I have a flot line graph which has dates as the x-axis. At the moment my dates are wrong because my local timeset offset is not being added to the UTC time.

How can I make flot offset my times to use my local timezone offset?

I read a post on these forums saying to use timezone: "browser" in the x-axis specification but I've tried that and it is not working for me. At the moment I am not loading flot.timezone.js. Is that the reason it is not working or is there something else I need to look at?

Theses are the other modules I have loaded in....

```
<script src="resources/js/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/flot/jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/flot/jquery.flot.orderBars.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/flot/jquery.flot.stack.js"></script>
```

thanks

Comment: Can you handle it on the server side? Have you looked at this - [TimeZone Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663821/time-zone-problem-with-flot-jquery-plugin)

Comment: Thanks. Yes. I've changed the code to handle it on the server side. I did see that post but it seemed like there were two possible answers. Since the browser keyword did not work for me I guess server side is safest.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this applies to you, but sometimes you are dealing with three timezones: the timezone where the data was collected, the server timezone, and the browser timezone where the data is being displayed.  These can be different and can get very confusing.

I would suggest working in UTC right up until the time you have to display the data.  You can use a city for the timezone key instead of "browser".  I would also suggest using two objects to make your calculations: one with a city with a constant year-round offset from GMT and another with the number of milliseconds offset from GMT.  Both would use the timezone label(cst,cdt,est,etc) as the key.